# Android studio project unconfigured

Tags: android

Today, i started my android studio and all are unconfigured. Classes show a lot of errors. This is the error that android studio show me when i try to run the app:

Error:java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

[image]

This is my gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.garcia.coachtrain"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

i add the new gradle:



  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.garcia.coachtrain"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

If i put this sdk version, compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1' doesnt work. The java class doesnt found caldroid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it doing this:

File menu --> Invalidate caches / restart

In the warning window --> Select invalidate / restart

this solved me the problem and i keep this gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.garcia.coachtrain"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the sdk to latest version because your compile sdk version and build tools version are different.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "codingtown.coconut"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.8'
    compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.8'
}
```

Comment: because your compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" are not same

Comment: i change the compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" to compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "23.0.0" and it doesnt work.

Comment: Nidhin kumar, yesterday my project works correctly so i think that this is not the problem.

Comment: try to rebuild the project once

Comment: i try to rebuild again and again but it is the same. i am getting crazy

Comment: try to change the  buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'  to  buildToolsVersion '23.0.0' or go to file---> project structure and check buildtool version and check it to 23

Comment: i do that and doesnt work. i try also delete .gradle folder and restart android studio but doesnt work

Comment: my  buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' is the same than project structure buildtool

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and then restart android studio.